# Putting an if-else statement in an if statement (Java on Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement, curly-brackets

I was working on some assignments I had for my java class, and I came across this error:

```
public static final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";
public static final String ANSI_GREEN = "\u001B[32m";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to QuizApp! Programmed by Chris!");
    System.out.println("Please type the number corrisponding to the correct answer.");
    int score = 100;
    for(int i = 0;i <5;i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            System.out.println("What is the capital of America? ");
            System.out.println("1) Washington D.C \t2) New York");
            System.out.println("3) Philadelphia \t4) Manhatten");
            int answer = myScanner.nextInt();
            if (answer == 1) {
                System.out.println(ANSI_GREEN+"Correct!");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Either your answer was wrong, or there was a syntax error.");
                score = score - 20;
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                System.out.println("What ocean do emporer penguins swim in? ");
                System.out.println("1) The Indian Ocean \t2) The Pacific Ocean");
                System.out.println("3) The Atlantic Ocean \t4) The Antarctic Ocean");
                answer = myScanner.nextInt();
                if (answer == 4); {
                    System.out.println(ANSI_GREEN+"Correct!");
                }else{
                    System.out.println(ANSI_RED+"Either your answer was wrong, or there was a syntax error.");
                }
            }           
        }   
    }
}

}
```

It said I had an error with my curly brackets here:

```
        if (i == 1) {
            System.out.println("What ocean do emporer penguins swim in? ");
            System.out.println("1) The Indian Ocean \t2) The Pacific Ocean");
            System.out.println("3) The Atlantic Ocean \t4) The Antarctic Ocean");
            answer = myScanner.nextInt();
            if (answer == 4); {
                System.out.println(ANSI_GREEN+"Correct!");
            }else{
                    System.out.println(ANSI_RED+"Either your answer was wrong, or there was a syntax error.");
            }
        }
```

I was trying to put an if-else statement inside of an if statement. I know why its giving me this error, but I'm not sure how to fix it. (The error is most likely java thinking that the }else{ is paired with the first if statement.

Comment: Remove that semicolon after `if (answer == 4)`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here

```
if (answer == 4);
```

You have a semicolon after your `if` statement which terminates the condition. Remove it and you should be fine.